# How to improve closed question?

Tags: discussion

What can I do, to make [How can I seek permanent Personalised Assessment Arrangements, rather than applying each year?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/106810/75817) helpful to others? I don't think that PAA is specific to my case. Many others at other universities probably face this dilemma too...

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing that the primary issue is the leasing stuff. That's really your issue, and one that we can't give you any guidance on. If you just focus on why you want and need a permanent PAA, you might be able to get an answer. But right now it's a little too unfocused.

Comment: I have edited the question to bring the basic question into better focus, but leaving the contextual details in the question, for anyone who finds them helpful, optionally.  And I have voted to reopen.